# How to create html tags each with their ID via a button with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a button in html to click it executes a JavaScript function that creates a new field with id in a hidden div.

I wanted each new field (tag) has created its "ID" specifies, not an ID for everyone as is my code (below). I need to be different to record in the database that is entered in each.

Can you help me ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addpergunta').click(function () {
        var x = 1;
        var div = $('#perg-box');
        var divtext = $('<div />');
        var text = $('<select />');
        text.attr('class', 'form-control').attr('id', 'id-pergunta' + x);
        divtext.append(text);
        div.append(divtext);
        $('#div_perg').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: How will you know the ID is unique within your database when you create it on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 1
    $('#addpergunta').click(function () {
        var div = $('#perg-box');
        var divtext = $('<div />');
        var text = $('<select />');
        text.attr('class', 'form-control').attr('id', 'id-pergunta' + count);
        divtext.append(text);
        div.append(divtext);
        count++;
        $('#div_perg').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Accurate shot. Worked perfectly. Thank you !